# Source env variable resolved instead of local env variable

Tags: scripting, environment-variables, telnet

I am having the following issue with Enviroment variables:

In my linux server I have an enviroment variable HOSTNAME (has value SERVER_HOSTNAME)
In my Linux box I have another enviroment variable HOSTNAME (has value CLIENT_HOSTNAME)
I can vew both these variables with set command.

When I telnet from my Linux server to my Linux box, and do echo $HOSTNAME I get CLIENT_HOSTNAME

But when I run a script that performs this telnet and echo the HOSTNAME of Linux server(SERVER_HOSTNAME) is resolved instead of Linux box

My question is how can I get the CLIENT_HOSTNAME to be resolved inside the telnet session.
I have tried to use export bu that didnt help.

Thanks

Comment: Please show the script you refer to. I'm assuming that the script resolves the variable locally on the server, before even attempting to connect to the box.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.